# Access client variable within server-tags in vbscript

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have the following block of code that's im running in an asp-page:

```
 <script language="VBScript">
    sub ok_onclick()

        dim localVariable
        localVariable= "hello"

        <%
        call serversideFunction(localVariable)
        %>        

    end sub
```

The following block

```
<% call ServerSideFunction(localVariable) %>
```

Throws the following error:

> An unhandled exception ('Variable is undefined: 'localVariable'')
>   occurred in dllhost.exe [24184]

I've noticed that i can't put my local variables within the servercode-tags.

So my question is, how do send my local variable's value down to the server?

Comment: You need to understand that client-side as the name suggests runs at the client (Internet Browser) and server-side code runs at the server (Web Server). If you want to access a variable defined at the client in your server code it would have to be passed to the server as a request *(`HTTP GET` or `HTTP POST`)* via varying means *(HTML form to send a request or AJAX request to name a few)*. Then using the server-side code you would use `Request.QueryString("..")` *(`HTTP GET`)* or `Request.Form("...")` *(`HTTP POST`)* to access that data and assign it to a server-side local variable.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that due to the nature of server-side code in the example you provide the function `serversideFunction()` would have already been processed by the server before the response is sent to the client so trying to pass a variable from the client *(at which point doesn't exist because the server-side code must be processed before the HTTP response is sent to the client to be interpreted)* is a *["chicken or the egg"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_or_the_egg)* scenario. See [ASP Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524929.aspx)

Comment: I hope you're aware that client side VBScript only works on Internet Explorer. It doesn't even work on Edge - the default browser which ships with Win 10.

Comment: @John Yep, but scripting language aside the fundamentals apply to any client script in an Internet Browser. Valid point though especially if this is new development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Server-Side programming 101 which does sometimes catch people out but there are lots of good tutorials and articles out there that can help with understanding the fundamentals.

[image: Classic ASP Architecture]

*<sup>Image taken from [MSDN - ASP Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524929.aspx)</sup>*

> *<sub>Quote from [MSDN - ASP Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524929.aspx)</sub>*
>
> **IIS processes an ASP file in the following order when a request is received from a client:**
>
> 1. If an ISAPI filter is installed on the Web site, the ISAPI filters is processed first. This is true for all applications.
> 2. If the ASP application contains a Global.asa file in the root directory, the Global.asa is processed. Global.asa files specify event scripts and declare objects that have session or application scope. They do not display content; instead they stores event information and objects used globally by the ASP application.
> 3. In the requested ASP file, IIS separates the script blocks from the static HTML code blocks, reserving the static code in the response body.
> 4. IIS processes the script blocks. The script blocks might include transaction processing, database access calls, or calls to COM components in which case COM+ handles some of the processing.
> 5. After the ASP page script blocks are processed, their output is injected into the response body with the static HTML code.
> 6. The response is sent to the client.

The problem boils down to step 6. All the server-side processing is done before the response is sent to the client so in the example provided;

```
'Client-Side procedure
Sub ok_onclick()
  dim localVariable
  localVariable= "hello"
  <%
  'Server-Side code already processed before response
  'is returned to the client.
  Call serversideFunction(localVariable)
  %>        
End Sub
```

The `serversideFunction()` server-side function will have already executed before the client response is sent so will never know of the existence of `localVariable`.

In these situations you need to pass the `localVariable` data back to the Server using various tried and tested techniques *(HTML form, AJAX request etc)* that all boils down to communicating a `HTTP GET` or `HTTP POST` request that the Server can interpret and process.

Once you have sent the request the data can be picked up using the [ASP Request Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524948(v=vs.90).aspx) and passed into a Server-side variable.

```
<%
Dim serverVariable
'Request came via a HTTP GET.
serverVariable = Request.QueryString("localVariable")
'Request came via a HTTP POST.
serverVariable = Request.Form("localVariable")
'Request came via either a HTTP GET or HTTP POST
'Using this has it's overheads.
serverVariable = Request("localVariable")
%>
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [MSDN - ASP Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524929.aspx)